# unlink/delete files for every user uploaded file (with checkbox)

Tags: php

Hi how can I delete files for every user that he had uploaded in his account.
The location of files is my folder "uploader/".
I tried to put the code unlink("uploader/$row1");
$row1 is the filename of every uploaded file.

The code:

```
<?php
**// Check if delete button active**
$delete1 = $_POST['delete'];
if(isset($delete1)) {
$checkboxID =$_POST['checkbox'];
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkboxID[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM uploadedfiles WHERE fileid='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}

if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=myfiles.php\">";
$sucdel = "Deletion Successful.";
}

}
mysql_close();
?>
```

The checkboxes:

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><center><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row0; ?>">
    </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row1; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo "$row2 KB" ; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row3; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $dlfile; }?></center></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

Code that show all user uploaded files:

```
<?php
include "dbconnect.php";

$sql="SELECT * FROM uploadedfiles";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploadedfiles WHERE username='$usersess' ");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
$row0 = $row['fileid'];
$row1 = $row['name'];
$row2 = $row['size'];
$row3 = $row['type'];
$dlfile = "<a href='download.php?file=$row1'>Download</a>"; 

?>
```

IT IS ALL in one page. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: It would be possible if you know where the files are.  Without the filepath (which you don't seem to have in the DB) we can't know... wait, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//loop through an array from check boxes. it wont delete the actual file tho, bad to use coz its possible to delete other peoples files :/
if (isset($_POST["checkbox"])){
    $delArr = $_POST["checkbox"];
    foreach ($delArr as $id) {
        mysql_query('DELETE from uploadedfiles where fileid ="'.$id.'"');
    }
}

//so get the users file list first then loop through and delete each one, then remove the rows

if (isset($_POST["checkbox"]) && isset($_POST['user'])){
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT name from uploadedfiles where username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']).'"');
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            unlink('path_to_userfiles/'.$row['uploadedfiles']);
        }
        mysql_query('DELETE FROM uploadedfiles WHERE username ="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']).'"');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite confused, where will I exactly place this?

Comment: its just an example, adapt it. you could place it anywhere on the page its posted to. both examples will delete all files despite the checkbox

Comment: in your example, what is $db supposed to be?

Comment: sorry its nothing, i always put the connection at end of all query's, dirty habbit :/

Comment: i still not working. I tried to replace $row['uploadedfiles'] into $row['name'] where 'name' is the name field of the filename. And mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) into the user who is in $_SESSION (logged in).